# How to concatenate a dataframe to a multiindex main dataframe along columns

Tags: dataframe, concatenation, multi-index

I have tried a few answers but was not able to get the desired result in my case.

I am working with stocks data.
I have a list `['3MINDIA.NS.csv', 'AARTIDRUGS.NS.csv', 'AARTIIND.NS.csv', 'AAVAS.NS.csv', 'ABB.NS.csv']`
for every stock in the list I get an output which contains trades and related info.. it looks something like this:

```
               BUY         SELL         profits    rel_profits
0           2004-01-13  2004-01-27   -44.200012   -0.094606
1           2004-02-05  2004-02-16    18.000000    0.044776
2           2005-03-08  2005-03-11    25.000000    0.048077
3           2005-03-31  2005-04-01    13.000000    0.025641
4           2005-10-11  2005-10-26   -20.400024   -0.025342
5           2005-10-31  2005-11-04    67.000000    0.095578
6           2006-05-22  2006-06-05   -55.100098   -0.046693
7           2007-03-06  2007-03-14     3.000000    0.001884
8           2007-03-19  2007-03-28    41.500000    0.028222
9           2007-07-31  2007-08-14    69.949951    0.038224
10          2008-01-24  2008-02-05    25.000000    0.013055
11          2009-11-04  2009-11-05    50.000000    0.031250
12          2010-12-10  2010-12-15    63.949951    0.018612
13          2011-02-02  2011-02-15   -53.050049   -0.015543
14          2011-09-30  2011-10-07    74.799805    0.018181
15          2015-12-09  2015-12-18  -215.049805   -0.019523
16          2016-01-18  2016-02-01  -475.000000   -0.046005
17          2016-11-16  2016-11-30 -1217.500000   -0.096877
18          2018-03-26  2018-04-02     0.250000    0.000013
19          2018-05-22  2018-05-25   250.000000    0.012626
20          2018-06-05  2018-06-12   101.849609    0.005361
21          2018-09-25  2018-10-10 -2150.000000   -0.090717
22          2021-01-27  2021-02-03   500.150391    0.024638
23          2021-06-30  2021-07-07   393.000000    0.016038
24          2021-08-12  2021-08-13   840.000000    0.035279
25                 NaN         NaN -1693.850281    0.995277

# note: every dataframe will have a last row with NaN values in buy, sell columns
# each datafram has different number of rows
```

Now I tried to add an extra level of index to this dataframe like this:

```
symbol = name of the stock from given list for ex. for 3MINDIA.NS.csv symbol is 3MINDIA

trades.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[symbol], trades.columns])
```

after this I tried to concatenate each `trades` dataframe that is generated in the loop to a main dataframe using:

```
result_df = pd.concat([result_df, trades], axis=1)

# I am trying to do this so that Whenever 
I call result_df[symbol] I should be able 
to see the trade dates for that particular symbol.
```

But I get a result_df that has lot of `NaN` values because each `trades` dataframe has variable number of rows in it.

IS there any way I can combine `trades` dataframes along the columns with stock symbol as higher level index and not get all the `NaN` values in my `result_df`

`result_df` I got

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way to get what I wanted.
first I added this code in loop

```
trades = pd.concat([trades], keys=[symbol], names=['Stocks'])
```

after this I used concatenate again on `result_df` and `trades`

```
# Desired Result
result_df = pd.concat([result_df, trades], axis=0, ignore_index=False)
```

And BAM!!! This is exactly what I wanted

[image: Desired_result]